# Movie where little boy disappears from his room after thunder strikes the house

Tags: identify-this-movie

I can't seem to stop recollecting old movies in my memory. I just started to remember a scene I saw probably between 1994 and 1995 (the release date must be no older than the 80s though). There was a little boy in his room, in the second floor of a common house (white I think). It was night and he seemed a little scared if I remember well. I remember an old man in the house (his grandfather?). It was raining heavily outside.

Suddenly, a thunder hit the house, and someone (I believe it was the old man but I might be wrong) came into the boy's room to see he was not there anymore. My memory then flashes a picture of him and his family (during the same scene). It sounded like the boy was gone forever, but I don't remember what exactly happened to him, of if I saw the full movie. I was really little back then, but I remember that scene kinda scared me out at the time.

I wonder if this rings a bell to someone.

Comment: Reflecting on what I just wrote, makes me think that the thunder was a symbolic way to show the boy has in fact died at that moment.

Comment: Invaders from mars 1953
Thunder then alien saucer lands

Answer (score 4):

There is a scene at the start of [Labyrinth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091369/) that is very similar, but it is the boys older sister, not an old man.

The boy was kidnapped by the goblin king (at the prompting of the sister) and taken to (wait for it) the labyrinth, prompting the girl to venture after him.

There is also the movie [House](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091223/) where the mans son is taken-by/disappears-into a possessed house, but I can't recall the exact scene where this happens.

Answer (score 1):

There was an episode of Fact or Fiction (a US TV show hosted by Star Trek: TNG's Jonathan Frakes) where a boy was playing in his room and went into a closet.  When the sister opened the closet door, the boy had vanished.  At the end of the episode, they actually stated that vignette was factual.  That show aired in the late 90's.

Answer (score -2):

In "Pay The Ghost" a boy disappears and key scenes are in his bedroom.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Can you explain why you think this is the right movie? How does it relate to the information given in the question?

Comment: also, its Nicholas Cage in Pay the Ghost, not Bruce Willis.

Comment: Well, I googled, looking for the name of pay the ghost(with the wrong actor) and was sent here.  Figured since this was an old post more might come if I bumped.  After the premadonnas' negative marks, I will no longer use your site.  Goodbye.